# leaflet.js: Fire event when setView() has finished the animation. How is that possible?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm currently working with leaflet.js and I'm searching the web now for quite a bit, to find out: If there is an event, that can be fired after animation end of asynchronous function setView().

This is what I tried:

```
map.setView( [lat, lon ], 12 , { 
   pan: { animate: true , duration: 0.5 }, 
   zoom: { animate: true }, 
   animate: true
}.on('ready', function(e) {
   console.log("animation finished!");
});
```

The setView-command works perfectly, but the function, that should be fired when map-animation is ready, is not working.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried the [`moveend`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-moveend) and [`zoomend`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomend) events?

You can attach a callback on both events easily: `map.once("moveend zoomend", callback)` (note the `once` that will remove the listener once it is triggered)

A very special case may not trigger your callback: if `setView` does not change anything, i.e. the requested view is already the current view. To be checked, it is possible that the `moveend` event is fired by `setView` in all cases.

Otherwise, a simple timeout could be enough.Especially since you specify the animation duration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`moveend`** event which is fired by Leaflet after setView finishes:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-moveend

`map.on('moveend', function(e){console.log("test")})`;

However this is fired every time when map is moved so you need to set some flag before calling `setView`, and resetting that flat in `moveend` handler.

Comment: I think this is a good use for [once](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#evented-once)

Answer (score 0):

For `moveend`

```
map.on('moveend', function () {
    console.log("moveend"); 
});
```

And for `zoomend`

```
map.on('zoomend', function () {
    console.log("zoomend");      
});
```

Or for both

```
map.on('moveend zoomend', function () {
    console.log("moveend || zoomend");  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that we must use a promise for this purpose.

```js
const moveTo = (position: GeoPosition) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         const leafletPos = position.toLeafletPosition();
         const handler = () => resolve();
         map.panTo(leafletPos);
         map.once('moveend zoomend', handler);
    });
};
```