# Leaflet Bounds Not Updated

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a problem with a function allowing to change the position of a marker on my leaflet map.
I update the coordinates of my map with a zoom to 17.
However when I call my recupObjectByLatLong function by passing mapRef.current.getBounds (), the map has not yet updated the bounds in relation to the zoom of the new coordinates.

To prevent the problem today, I put a setTimeout, however I don't think this is the cleanest solution ...

```
function changePositionMarker(e) {

    const latitude = e.latlng.lat;
    const longitude = e.latlng.lng;

    mapRef.current.setView(L.latLng(latitude, longitude), 17);

    markerRef.current.setLatLng([latitude, longitude]);

    markerRef.current.bindPopup('test').openPopup();

    setTimeout(() => {
      recupObjectByLatLong(mapRef.current.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat, mapRef.current.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng, mapRef.current.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat, mapRef.current.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng);
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean that the setView action has not completed, so without the timeout, `recupObjectByLatLong` does not yet have the values that you are waiting for it to have once the map view has finished moving?  If so, check out [leaflet.js: Fire event when setView() has finished the animation. How is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565068/leaflet-js-fire-event-when-setview-has-finished-the-animation-how-is-that-po)

Comment: Indeed this is exactly what is happening! when I integrated the setTimeout that immediately solved my problem. I looked at your link and indeed it looks a lot like it. Thank you !